# Cannot change values in EF despite using SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble updating values in Entity Framework 6, I've looked thoroughly through the internet for answers but it seems I'm doing everything just fine, yet I can't seem to make it work.

It's worth mentioning that adding entities into the DB works just fine, meaning I can add products/users in my project to the DB, but not update them.
This is homework.

```
 public bool ChangeAccountStatus(long userID, bool isUserActive)
    {
        User userToChange = GetUserById(userID); // Gets the user whose values I want to change.
        using (var context = new ShopContext())
        {
            if (userToChange != null)
            {
                if (isUserActive)
                {
                    userToChange.IsActive = false;
                    context.SaveChanges();

                }

                else
                {
                    userToChange.IsActive = true;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I can make the update work if I use linq to find the user whose value I want to change, but I don't want too much code-duplication in my project, and I'm using the same linq (function GetUserById) in many other functions.
Do I need to use linq to access the user from the database, instead of using a function I created to avoid code-duplication?
This is the GetUserById function:

```
        public User GetUserById(long userId) 
    {
        using (var context = new ShopContext())
        {
            var userToFind = context.UsersTable
                .Where((u) => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (userToFind != null)
                return userToFind;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retrieving an entity from one context, then calling `SaveChanges()` on a different context. If you inline the method, it becomes more clear:

```
var userToChange;
using (var context = new ShopContext())
{
    userToChange = context.UsersTable.Where((u) => u.Id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
}

using (var context = new ShopContext())
{
    if (userToChange != null)
    {
        if (isUserActive)
        {
            userToChange.IsActive = false;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            userToChange.IsActive = true;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The second context doesn't know anything about userToChange, because it isn't tracking it. You can tell it to though:

```
context.UsersTable.Attach(userToChange);
```

As an aside, you have some redundant code there - an if statement, which assigns a boolean to true or false can be simplified:

```
if (isUserActive)
    userToChange.IsActive = false;
else
    userToChange.IsActive = true;

// Equivalent to:
userToChange.IsActive = !isUserActive;
```

And the null check is not necessary:

```
if (userToFind != null)
    return userToFind;
else
    return null;

// Equivalent to:
return userToFind;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you very much for the help, and for helping me with the redundant code. Appreciated!!